# Can't receive FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) on iphone via api from web(chrome)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have question,
I have api that send FCM to my device, but it's strange to me, because its work on android but doesnt work on my iphone. I tried to send FCM via postman and it's work on both my devices(android and iphone). So, is there "special" configuration for send FCM via api from web to Iphone?

Comment: Chrome on iOS is just a wrapper around WebKit, which doesn't support Web Push.

Comment: thanks sir, but it's can be conclude that push fcm via api from chrome doesnt work?

Comment: Corect. Since delivery messages to the browser via FCM depends on Web Push, it won't work on iOS - as all browser there are based on Web Kit/Safari, which doesn't support this standard.

Comment: I see, so that's why my iphone can't receive fcm notifications sent from chrome.. thanks for help sir